# .Net Framework Web Api SelfHost service stopped suddenly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, self-host-webapi

- I created a simple Web Api selfHost as windows service which listens to an address which is dynamically loads from the database and normally it includes port number( like : http://localhost:1900)
  When I change the address( for example port number, something like http://localhost:1901) the service can catch the requests on the new port but the requests on old port ( http:localhost:1900) leads to crashing the service and it will be stopped.
  I just could debug my service and saw just NullReference Error and not any more info about it.
  I don't know even where this error happened and non of my logs could help me.
  what do you think about this error? Have you ever seen this kind of error before?
- For more info I should say just some errors I can see in Event Viewer window :
- Application: {Service.exe}
  Framework Version: v4.0.30319
  Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
  Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
  at System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostServer+d__35.MoveNext()
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
  at System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostServer+d__34.MoveNext()
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_1(System.Object)
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
- Faulting application name: {Service.exe}, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xc594704b
  Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3383, time stamp: 0x5ddcb9ff
  Exception code: 0xe0434352
  Fault offset: 0x000dc232
  Faulting process id: 0x7370
  Faulting application start time: 0x01d72886545b1d41
  Faulting application path: {Service PhysicalAddress}
  Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
  Report Id: 305c75f4-8c83-484a-b673-565abfc2b7d6
  Faulting package full name:
  Faulting package-relative application ID
- For more details I bring my Service Class Body below :

  ```
  class service
   {
    HttpSelfHostConfiguration config;
    HttpSelfHostServer server;
    Timer _timer = new Timer();

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _timer.Interval = 2000;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listenToUrl = _getDestUrlFromDB();
        var configChanged = false;
        if (config != null && config.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri != listenToUrl + "/")
        {
            configChanged = true;
            config.Dispose();
        }
        config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(uploadApiUrl.Data);
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default",
                                    "api/{controller}/{id}",
                                    new { controller = "Home", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        if (server == null)
        {
            server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            var task = server.OpenAsync();
            task.Wait();

        }
        else if (configChanged)
        {

            try
            {
                Process.Start("cmd", $@"netsh http add urlacl url={listenToUrl} ");
                Process.Start("cmd", $@"delete urlacl url={listenToUrl} ");
                server.Dispose();
                server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
                var task = server.OpenAsync();
                task.Wait();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }

    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: *Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException at System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostServer.* Can yoi post some code at how the server is set up?

Comment: thank you @(Peter Bons) for your replying but no! that wasn't my answer, I know what does NullReference mean but my question was that how can I find out where does it come from? because I had set varous log in my code and didn't get anything

Comment: @PeterBons I edited my question and added my class